# How to enable dark theme for Qt applications?

Tags: xfce, qt, dark-mode

How can I enable a dark theme for Qt applications, while running from XFCE/i3/etc (NOT from Plasma)?

If your main DE is Plasma, the task is easy: you just switch your Plasma's style. However, Qt doesn't really pick up styles from gtk-based systems such as XFCE.

Answer (score 4):

- Install qt5ct. On Debian/Ubuntu: `apt install qt5ct`. On ArchLinux `pacman -S --needed qt5ct`.
- Set the environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`

  - If you want, you can do it globally by creating `/etc/environment.d/100qt5ct-dark-theme.conf` with the text `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` inside.
  - Alternatively, you can add `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` to your `~/.profile`
- Launch `qt5ct` once, select "Fusion" as your Theme and select "darker" color scheme in Appearance > Palette > Custom > Color scheme > "darker".
- Re-login so that your DE is re-started with this environment already set.

All Qt apps should now be in Dark theme by default now!

Comment: Does this also work for KDE applications such as okular?

Comment: @maxschlepzig Okular has its own Theme selector built-in, so you don't *need* to use this solution. That being said, since all KDE apps are built on Qt as far as I know, setting the Qt Theme will by default also affect okular, so it should be good right away.

Comment: Unfortunately, on Fedora 39, this doesn't work for me. That means pure Qt applications like vlc are properly rendered in dark-mode, qt5ct has zero effect on KDE applications such as okular and quassel.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Are you running Fedora 39 with KDE as the Desktop Environment? Or with non-KDE?

Comment: I'm running it with gnome shell. See also some more details in my related question/answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763457/configure-qt-darkmode

Comment: This does work for me on Arch xfce