# Configure Qt darkmode

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell, qt, dark-mode

After upgrading from Fedora 37 to 39 Qt applications such as vlc aren't rendered in dark mode anymore, when starting them from a dark-mode-configured gnome shell session.

Apparently, Qt application are supposed to render in dark mode, by default, in Fedora 39, according to https://jgrulich.cz/2023/08/22/qt-theming-in-fedora-workstation/ - but they don't, on my system.

Gtk applications such as Gnome shell settings are rendered in dark mode and Gnome shell config reads:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
'prefer-dark'
```

After the Fedora upgrade, autoremove etc. the following adwaita packages are installed:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep adwaita
adwaita-cursor-theme-45.0-1.fc39.noarch
adwaita-icon-theme-45.0-1.fc39.noarch
qadwaitadecorations-qt6-0.1.3-2.fc39.x86_64
qadwaitadecorations-qt5-0.1.3-2.fc39.x86_64
libadwaita-1.4.2-2.fc39.x86_64
adwaita-gtk2-theme-3.28-17.fc39.x86_64
```

How can I debug this further?

How I fix the Gnome shell dark mode integration for Qt applications?

Or, alternatively, how do I configure dark mode for all Qt applications, by default?

Comment: Similar question: [How to enable dark theme for Qt applications?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/745499/1131)

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 39, there are also the adwaita-qt6/adwaita-qt5 packages available for providing Gnome shell styling to Qt applications. However, the adwaita-qt project [is unmaintained](https://github.com/FedoraQt/adwaita-qt) and this shows, i.e. forcing a dark adwaita theme via `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=Adwaita-Dark` kind of works, but the dark mode is incomplete, e.g. the menu bar is still light.

---

A workaround is to install the `kvantum` theme 'engine' whose default theme is dark-mode styled.

Thus, the following is sufficient to run vlc under Dark Mode:

```
$ export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum
$ vlc
```

or

```
$ QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum vlc
```

NB: Unlike Qt4, with Qt5 and above the style can't be configured via some dotfile in `$HOME`, instead one has to [work](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications) with environment [variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications).

Unfortunately, the kvantum default settings aren't perfect, out of the box, either. For example, normal panel labels in vlc and okular are in black font on gray background, e.g. the played and remaining time - which of course make them hard to read.

---

Another partial workaround is to install `qt5ct` and configure the Qt Fusion style with a custom palette, i.e. color scheme 'darker':

```
$ QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct qt5ct
```

Such that:

```
$ head -n 6 ~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf        
[Appearance]
color_scheme_path=/usr/share/qt5ct/colors/darker.conf
custom_palette=true
standard_dialogs=default
style=Fusion
```

Again, for Qt programs to actually use all this, an environment variable has to be set. This time it's `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME`, though.

Example:

```
$ QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct vlc
```

This yields much better dark-mode styling for vlc, i.e. the playtime/remaining time labels are now also displayed as white text on dark grey background and there aren't any glitches, anymore.

However, on KDE programs such as okular, this workaround is ineffective. That means okular simply uses its default light-mode styling and nothing is changed, at all.

Comment: 2017 Kavium issue on black on black/grey font glitches in KDE applications: https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/issues/122#issuecomment-305536434